# Standard Haskell function :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe b

Tags: haskell

There is a standard [tryPick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353814%28v=vs.120%29.ASPX) function if F# that returns the first (from left-to-right if any at all) successful application of a function on an element of a list. I am hopping there is a standard function like that in Haskell. I [tried](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20Maybe%20b%29%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20Maybe%20b) Hoogle and didn't find anything.

I am new to Haskell and I am not sure what the right way of doing it is. Would you do it like this:

```
tryPick:: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe b
tryPick try xs = case Maybe.mapMaybe try xs of
    [] -> Nothing
    (x:_) -> Just x
```

?

Comment: One of the functions in Data.Maybe can already handle the cases you’ve written.

Answer (score 16):

You want:

```
tryPick :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe b
tryPick f as = msum (map f as)
```

I'll explain how this works.

`map f as` produces a list of possible `Maybe` actions to try:

```
map f as :: [Maybe b]
```

`msum` tries them sequentially until one succeeds (returning the value as a `Just`) or they all fail (returning a `Nothing`).  For example:

```
> msum [Nothing, Just 2, Just 3, Nothing]
Just 2
> msum [Nothing, Nothing]
Nothing
```

Note that `msum`'s type is more general, so we can generalize the signature to:

```
tryPick :: (MonadPlus m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m b
```

This will now work for any `MonadPlus`.  Have fun discovering what it does for other `MonadPlus` types.

Comment: `tryPick f = foldr (mplus . f) mzero :: (MonadPlus m, Foldable t) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m b`, best of both worlds!

Comment: "As of base 4.8.0.0, msum is just asum, specialized to MonadPlus." I'd personally always use asum rather than msum today.

Answer (score 14):

The `listToMaybe` function in `Data.Maybe` looks pretty good:

```
tryPick f = listToMaybe . mapMaybe f
```

Comment: Does this incur extra memory overhead from mapping over the whole list? I'm not sure if GHC will create a thunk for the rest of the computation or optimize it away

Comment: @jozefg It terminates given an infinite list, so intuitively it’s fine.

Comment: @jozefg I'd think so. Mentally inlining we'd have `\(x:xs) -> case (f x) : tryPick f xs of { [] -> Nothing; (y:_) -> Just y }`

Comment: I know it terminates I was curious about whether this will produce an extra thunk or whether it's optimized away. It's not a huge deal, more of a curiosity. Btw +1 for a clearer solution than mine

Comment: Doesn't this, on multiple successful applications, return a Just list instead of Just the first successful application?

Answer (score 12):

It's not necessarily the simplest solution, but I feel it important to highlight the `First` `Monoid` based solution. I think it's the prettiest.

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, foldMap)

tryPick :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe b
tryPick f = getFirst . foldMap (First . f)     -- this is just `foldMap f`
                                               -- with the "firsty" Maybe Monoid
```

This is also immediately generalizable to any `Foldable` with precisely the same code

```
tryPick :: Foldable t => (a -> Maybe b) -> t a -> Maybe b
```

`Foldable` instances provide ways to "smash" all of the elements together in order using `Monoid`s. The `First` `Monoid` defined as

```
newtype First a = First { getFirst :: Maybe a }
```

is a specialization of `Maybe` with a `mappend` operation that picks the "first" or "leftmost" `Just`.

So, putting them together, `getFirst . foldMap (First . f)` computes your `(a -> Maybe b)` function over all of the `a`s in the `[a]`, then smashes the results together with the rule that the "first" `Just` wins.

Comment: `Alt` and `getAlt` are more modern alternatives for `First` and `getFirst`.

Answer (score 8):

I'm coming a bit late to the party, but here's a variation on J. Abrahamson's answer that uses Conor McBride's lovely `ala'` function from the [`newtype` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype):

```
import Control.Newtype (ala')
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, foldMap)
import Data.Monoid (First(..))

tryPick :: (Foldable t) => (a -> Maybe b) -> t a -> Maybe b
tryPick = ala' First foldMap
```

This may seem a bit cryptic, but I find the way it decouples the "collection vessel" (`First`) from the "collection scheme" (`foldMap`) and both from the "preprocessing function" (`a -> Maybe b`) -- all while hiding `newtype` wrapping and unwrapping -- rather beautiful. `ala` has been in my experience a fine tool for creating beautiful code, and I'd like to plug it. Thanks, Conor!

Comment: This is the most awesome answer I've seen for a long time. I just learned something very usefull. Thanks!